# tsc compile AMD module with specified module id

Tags: typescript, amd

is it possible to config typescript compiler to compile exported class with define module id?

typescript

```
export class Foo {...}
```

this is what tsc output (module: "amd")

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {...}
```

expected

```
define("Foo", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {...}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> expected `define("Foo")`

Use the super secret `/// <amd-module name="Foo"/>`

But I would advise against this as it will make your code needlessly amd specific.

Comment: thank you very much, its what i need.  

may you explain more specific regarding "needlessly amd specific"?  

in my case, the project contain a lot of class, around 80 and growing  
it was too many http request, and we trying to merge some common use classes in to single bundle,  so that we can load manually each time using <script> tag  
  
thank you

Comment: `needlessly amd specific`  look at http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: thank you for the link.  btw where you get the "super secret", is there others than amd-module and reference?