# Typescript, AMD and module names

Tags: typescript, gulp, amd

Is there a way to set the names of the compiled modules from *.ts?
Some tsconfig,json setting, or some Gulp pluggin that could do this.

Currently I'm getting

```
define([], function(){ .. })
```

But i wan't to be able to set the name like so:

```
define('module-name', [], function(){ .. })
```

Tried a few gulp pluggins but they overwrite the sourcemaps information and i loose the "ts debugging" ability in the browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tsc compile AMD module with specified module id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363604/tsc-compile-amd-module-with-specified-module-id)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a declaration at the top of your module to get the desired result:

```
///<amd-module name='foo-module'/>
```

This will result in

```
define('foo-module', [], function(){ .. })
```

being emitted by the compiler

Comment: I've been looking for this exact answer, thanks!